# Session not working in Laravel API

Tags: laravel-5

Usually I save temporary data/array inside session while working with Website (Non API).

Today I want to do the same thing (save temporary data/array inside session) with Laravel API.

So here is my route.

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'isMember'])->group(function () {

  Route::get('createSession', function (){
    $a = Session::put('example', 'this is example session.');
    return "session created";
  });

  Route::get('getSession', function () {
    return Session::get('example');
  });

});
```

When I visit `/api/createSession` it return `session created`, but when I visit `/api/getSession` it return nothing.

**So how do I work with session inside API?**

What I think why this not work because API use Token based authentication instead of Session based Authentication, refer to `config/auth.php` Authentication Guards section.

**If work with session inside API is consider as bad practice, What is your suggestion to save temporary data/array inside API for shared hosting?**

What I have tried so far is save data/array in `Storage::disk(local)` but I don't think it best practice.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I will use Session to store temporary data about Cart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Middleware api did not include StartSession middleware, so you can not get the session. Check it here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php#L33

You can add middleware "web" to your route or add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to middleware api but I'm not recommended it. APIs should not use session.

Hope that it can help you.

Comment: Ah I see, so what is your personal recomendation to save data/array in API?

Comment: You can save it to file/database or using localStorage if you're working with javascript in client side.

Comment: Still it is not working after that changes.

Answer (score 1):

open  `app/Http/Kernel.php` and then , add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` on array  `protected $routeMiddleware` and add on `protected $middlewareGroups` on `api`[image]